# Disable Selecting of Empty Lines in ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox, selecteditem

I have a listBox with several items, inbetween each item there is a blank line, e.g.

```
item1

item2

item3
```

(The reason being is, with several dozen items it just looks a lot nicer IMO).

I want to make it so the user can't select any of the empty lines, I tried

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "")
            listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();
```

in the mouse_Down event, but I get this ugly flicker effect, and the above doesn't work when the user selects an actual item and uses arrow keys to scroll.

**EDIT**
Is there a way to adjust the vertical spacing between listBox items? That's all I'd need to do (then I can remove empty spaces)

Comment: Are you adding the blank lines just for spacing?  If so, you could just have the ItemTemplate for the rows in the Listbox have a margin around the box of 0,0,28,0 or so.  This way it will only have extra spacing at the bottom, keeping your current visual effect.  I'd avoid adding empty lines to your list just for spacing.

Comment: Yes that's the only reason.. I don't see an ItemTemplate property, is that it's name? I messed around with "Margin" but it didn't change the vertical spacing (or do anything that I could see).

Comment: Hard to tell if this is a Winforms or WPF question.  The Winforms solution is a simple one, use a ListView instead.  Which supports the Groups property, giving you a clean way to group items that includes a non-selectable group header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ListBox.ItemHeight property to define the line height of all items. Therefore you have to set DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed or OwnerDrawVariable and handle the DrawItem event.

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds);
                else
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);

                string text = listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString();

                e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top);                
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't need to set each item to be different. I tried setting ListBox.ItemHeight to several different values, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: You are right. Sorry. I've edited my answer and added some working code.